# Non-exhaustive patterns in function: Turning a string into a list of ord values

Tags: haskell, converters

I'm new to Haskell and coding in general and am having a bit of a problem.

```
sti :: [Char] -> [Integer]
sti "" = [fromIntegral (ord x)| x<-""]
```

So what I am trying to do with the above is create a list of integers from a string, for example `"Hello"` becomes `['H','e','l','l','o']` and then I turn that list into their respective ord values from `Data.Char`.

My problem is that when I try to use this function I get: Non-exhaustive patterns in function `sti`. Does this mean there are instances where I can't take the ord x of a string? And if so how would I go about fixing that?

Anything help would be appreciated.

Comment: `""` is an empty string, you need a variable instead. This question lacks minimal understanding of the problem. I suggest, you first visit www.learnyouahaskell.com

Comment: Or, once you understand this version, you could use `sti = fmap (fromIntegral . ord)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only handling the case of the empty string, `""`. You want this:

```
sti :: [Char] -> [Integer]
sti xs = [fromIntegral (ord x) | x <- xs]
```

`xs` is a variable and will match anything, which is what you want in this case.

Note that you can use pattern-matching to implement special cases, e.g.:

```
sti :: [Char] -> [Integer]
sti "" = [1,2,3]
sti xs = [fromIntegral (ord x) | x <- xs]
```

This function returns the ASCII character values of the characters in the input string, *except* when the input is the empty string, in which case it returns `[1,2,3]` instead. This can be a useful feature even if it's not what you want here.

If you *only* implement special cases, and leave cases for which you have defined no value for your function, you'll crash if you try to evaluate your function for those cases:

```
Prelude Data.Char> let sti "" = [fromIntegral (ord x) | x <- ""]
Prelude Data.Char> sti "foo"
*** Exception: <interactive>:9:5-45: Non-exhaustive patterns in function sti
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `""` as if it were a variable name. But in Haskell, it stands for *empty string* instead. So your function is only defined for empty strings, and will give you the non-exhaustive pattern error in all other cases.

You ought to replace that with a proper variable name.